# Windows 8.1 keeps wanting to repair itself after installing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualization, visual-studio-2013, repair-install

I have a hp 650 with virtualization enabled. I installed windows 8.1 pro. I also installed Visual Studio 2013 Pro. However, after installing VS 2013 and at some point rebooting, Windows refuses to load and eventually shows me the repair Windows options. I cannot get the system to boot into Windows 8.

Whilst I now know that Visual Studio 2013 is causing this, can anyone suggest how I go about diagnosing the problem and getting to the root of it? Has anyone had similar experiences and how did you resolve it? I need Visual Studio to do my work and cannot go and buy another laptop.

Comment: Could you provide more specifics about the problem, such as the exact error messages?

Comment: That's just the thing. No error messages .. nothing. Windows simply wants to repair itself. It shows the black screen with the windws logo and the spinning mouse cursor. It stays like that forever (couple of hours). Then I restart the machine (by switching it off and on again) and then windows goes into repair mode. I manage now to get windows to load from a restore point, but I'm still no closer to a solution